# Правильный json на страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Мой js:

```
var cart = {}; //моя корзина

function init() {
    //вычитываем файл goods.json
    $.getJSON("goods.json", goodsOut);
}

function goodsOut(data) {
    //вывод на страницу
    var out = '';
    for (var key in data) {
        out+='<tr class="cart_tovar">';
        out+='<td>';
        out+='<p class="tovar_name">'+data[key].MED_NAME+'</p>';
        out+='</td>';
        out+='<td>';
        out+='<p class="tovar_manufacturer">'+data[key].VENDOR_NAME+'</p>';
        out+='<p class="tovar_country">'+data[key].COUNTRY_NAME+'</p>';
        out+='</td>';
        out+='<td class="tovar_cost">от '+data[key].RPRICE+' ₽</td>';
        out+='<td class="tovar_apteka">'+data[key].apteki+'</td>';
        out+='<td>';
        out+='<button class="add-to-cart" data-id="'+key+'">В корзину</button>';
        out+='</td>';
        out+='</tr>';
    }
    $('.goods-out').html(out);
    $('.add-to-cart').on('click', addToCart);
}

function addToCart() {
    //добавляем товар в корзину
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    if (cart[id]!=undefined) {
        cart[id]++;
    }
    else {
        cart[id] = 1;
    }
    showMiniCart();
    saveCart();
}

function saveCart() {
    //сохраняю корзину в localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
}

function showMiniCart(){
    //показываю содержимое корзины
    var out = Object.keys(cart).length;
    $('.mini-cart').html(out);
}

function loadCart() {
    //проверяю есть ли в localStorage запись car
    if (localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
        //если есть - расшифровываю и записываю в переменную cart
        cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
        showMiniCart();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    init();
    loadCart();
});
```

[Ссылка на сам json](https://dropmefiles.com/buL4B)

Не выводит ничего на страницу, ошибок тоже нету, подскажите путь решения проблемы.

Comment: вставьте уже `console.log(data);` и `console.log(out);` в начало и конец функции `goodsOut`

Comment: А вы думали я не делал этого?

Comment: да, думаю - не делали. Если делали, почему не рассказали?

Comment: потому что нету ошибок, просто файл не подгружается и все

Comment: точнее он подгружается, но на страницу не выводит каталог

Comment: То есть Вы не скажете, что вывелось в консоль браузера?

Comment: сейчас скрин скину, что ничего

Comment: https://pastenow.ru/6cb6f4084e487df93cda32b3ba196322

Comment: Что я должен понять из этой картинки? В функции `goodsOut` есть вызовы `console.log`? A в `init`? Вы в эти функции вообще попадаете?

Comment: везде где нужно проставил,а толку нет

Comment: я отказываюсь дальше это обсуждать и закрываю закладку браузера с Вашим вопросом. "Где нужно", "толку нет" - что это значит известно только Вам. На мои вопросы Вы отвечать не хотите.

Comment: хорошо,понял вас

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы дебажить этот метод jquery используйте код ниже. Читайте подробнее на [странице с  документацией](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

```
var cart = {}; //моя корзина

function init() {
    //вычитываем файл goods.json
    $.getJSON("goods.json", function(data) {
     console.log( "success" );
     goodsOut(data);
    })
      .done(function() {
        console.log( "second success" );
      })
      .fail(function(req, errMessage, error) {
        console.log( "error", error );
      })
      .always(function() {
        console.log( "complete" );
      });
}

function goodsOut(data) {
    //вывод на страницу
    var out = '';
    for (var key in data) {
        out+='<tr class="cart_tovar">';
        out+='<td>';
        out+='<p class="tovar_name">'+data[key].MED_NAME+'</p>';
        out+='</td>';
        out+='<td>';
        out+='<p class="tovar_manufacturer">'+data[key].VENDOR_NAME+'</p>';
        out+='<p class="tovar_country">'+data[key].COUNTRY_NAME+'</p>';
        out+='</td>';
        out+='<td class="tovar_cost">от '+data[key].RPRICE+' ₽</td>';
        out+='<td class="tovar_apteka">'+data[key].apteki+'</td>';
        out+='<td>';
        out+='<button class="add-to-cart" data-id="'+key+'">В корзину</button>';
        out+='</td>';
        out+='</tr>';
    };
    console.log(2, typeof out, out);
    $('.goods-out').html(out);
    $('.add-to-cart').on('click', addToCart);
}

function addToCart() {
    //добавляем товар в корзину
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    if (cart[id]!=undefined) {
        cart[id]++;
    }
    else {
        cart[id] = 1;
    }
    showMiniCart();
    saveCart();
}

function saveCart() {
    //сохраняю корзину в localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
}

function showMiniCart(){
    //показываю содержимое корзины
    var out = Object.keys(cart).length;
    $('.mini-cart').html(out);
}

function loadCart() {
    //проверяю есть ли в localStorage запись car
    if (localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
        //если есть - расшифровываю и записываю в переменную cart
        cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
        showMiniCart();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    init();
    loadCart();
});
```

В Вашем конкретном случае JSON невалидный:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token р in JSON at position 643187
>       at parse ()
>       at Ut (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at k (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery.min.js:2)

Answer (score 0):

Могу добавить к предыдущему ответу, что вы можете проверить свой json, например, [на этом сайте](https://jsonformatter.org/)


Ошибка в вашем json в том что попадаются символы, которые не может распарсить функция `JSON.parse`. 

А именно обратный слеш `\`. 

Для того чтобы решить эту проблему вы можете заменить его на прямой слеш `/` или экранировать обратный слеш, вот так `/\`